# Why isn't my .NET garbage being collected?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a data intense application where a user can select between different accounts.  Only one account can be selected at a time and this forces data to be loaded from the database.  I can see in Windows Task Manager the memory allocated to my application is increasing when I load an account to approximately half a gig.

We also have the ability to "unload" an account whereby we delete all of the objects (or at least we think we do) in memory.  However long I leave the application running dormant on my PC it never seems to decrease the allocated memory back to pre-loading account state even though if I look at the object states using `WeakReference` is says its not ALIVE.

If I explicitly call `GC.Collect()` at the end of the unload method then I can see the memory being unallocated or at least the size of the program in Windows Task Manager going down.  This is what we'd really like to accomplish in terms of memory as some users have experienced out-of-memory exceptions.

I know the garbage collector is doing some management because if I load subsequent accounts the memory never really increases much past half a gig so I think the GC has collected the previous account's data just like it should have done when unloading the account.

Should I continue to use GC.Collect considering the cost of running this relative to loading an account from the DB is minimal even though it is considered "bad practice" to explicitly call this?

Comment: Do not trust the TaskManager in cases of Memory.  Use something more trusty as the performance-monitor (type perfmon in widows to execute it) that shows the working set as well as private bytes.

Comment: Thanks for this comment - I shall use this going forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you describe it seems that you are somehow keeping hard references from items that you load from db. If you are using Entity framework or NHibernate, please check that you are disposing the context that you are using to load the data from your database as it will hold references for everything that you load in order to provide change tracking capabilities. Generally make sure that you are not keeping a reference somehow and be aware that sometimes this can be tricky; a good example of a tricky hard reference is loading some stuff in a lamda method which uses a method-scope variable, which gets auto-promoted to class variable because of being referenced inside the lamda method.

Comment: Interesting you mention this as we're using the legacy LinqToSQL ORM for our data access.  We're unable to disable the change tracking in the ORM as we have code dependant upon the Lazy loading pattern in that you can't have deferred loading enabled and change tracking disabled (I'm assuming the event registration for change tracking notifications maybe keeping those objects alive).  We originally had the memory exception being thrown as the context wasn't being explicitly disposed of, disposing of this during an account change has reduced this problem.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The GC collection is only triggered under [certain events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#conditions_for_a_garbage_collection) (eg the allocated memory for the hosting process is all used and it needs to allocate more, so it first check if it can collect some garbage).

The OM exception is probably not caused by this, but that either you have a memory leak somewhere else, or certain users are trying to load more than one account (or even a bigger than 0.5GB one). Consider doing some memory profiling on your application. (I have used [YourKit profiler](https://www.yourkit.com/dotnet/) for this and its pretty easy to use)

Think that if your process is x86 it has a maximum of 2GB available, so with such big data is not uncommon you get to the limit.

Comment: So in other words I shouldn't question the .NET runtime on when GC takes place and refrain from using GC.Collect? If I receive an Out-of-memory exception then I should focus on finding the memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if you did this in your code but a using statement will call the Dispose() method of the command that you are using.  It might help with the GC that you are having an issue with. Otherwise you are letting the system handle it.  The only issue is that the class you are using has to implement IDisposable.

```
    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "sp_SaveSomething";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@x", xxx));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ORG", ORG));        
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```